# Differences between Macro level and Micro level in translating

Tags: grammar, translation

there
What does the following paragraph mean by ***Macro level and Micro level*** concerning translation?

As for identifying the persona of the reviser of the translation, it is strictly connected to
identifying the moment in time at which the revision process has to be carried out; ***in other words ‘who’ is the reviser also depends and is interrelated
with the discussion on at ‘which level’ of the translation process revision is
expected to take place***. According to the BSEN15038:2006 stand ard (British
Standards Institution 2006: 11), revising translation is a compulsory stage in
a professional and quality-oriented translation process ***at its macro level***, and
it should be conducted by a person other than the translator. Mossop (2007a: 6)
speaks of two types of revision: unilingual and comparative revision. When
conducting a unilingual revision, the reviser focuses on the TT as a text in its
own right in order to determine any unidiomatic and incorrect use of language,
any textual errors and the like and only checks with the ST occasionally. This
procedure is similar, to a certain degree, to what an editor does (see editing
later in this section). When conducting a comparative revision, the reviser,
however, checks the TT in terms of accuracy and completeness by comparing
it with the ST (cf. Rasmussen and Schojoldager 2011: 90). When the procedure is conducted by the translator him/herself, it is not revision anymore; it is named checking by BSEN15038:2006 stand ard (British Standards Institute)

Also the following chart would be helpful.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the source of the text? Have you looked at dictionary definitions, and, if so, how don't they fit the context?

Comment: The source is the book''The Routledge Course in Translation Annotation Arabic-English-Arabic by Ali Almanna''.

Comment: I'm not convinced ***macro*** and ***micro*** are useful terms in the cited context. In [a different context](https://www.everydaysociologyblog.com/2011/05/micro-meets-macro-walking-in-your-community.html), one can distinguish between them on the basis of ***Macro-level** sociology looks at **large-scale** social processes, such as social stability and change. **Micro-level** sociology looks at **small-scale** interactions between individuals, such as conversation or group dynamics.* But the only difference between #1 and #2 seems to be whether the translator or someone else does the checking.

Comment: (Perhaps something was "lost in translation" from the original Arabic translator's thoughts! :)

Comment: This person is presenting a theory of translation. It is not a well-edited text. Also, we do not know whether it is a translation. That said, this author has decided to use macro and micro and has defined them. These are not good terms for what he is trying to describe. A translator does not work "at a micro level" as opposed to editors who edit translations working at a "macro level". However, Routledge is a very well-known publisher.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a well-written text.

> the moment in time when the revision process has to be carried out

is a verbose and pretentious way to say

> when the revision is performed.

The general meaning of "macro" is "when viewed on a large scale" whereas the general meaning of "micro" is "when viewed on a small scale." This text, however, seems to be using it in a different sense, which may be accepted among editors, etc. or may have been previously defined in this text.

What "macro" seems to mean in context is "not performed by the translator" and therefore subject to a more cursory review than the "detailed checking" done by the translator, which is identified as "micro" because it is more detailed than what this text implies is the casual "hit or miss" work done by revisors, editors, and proofreaders.

Without being snarky, the distinction may reflect an expectation in the publishing industry that translators are expected to provide highly intensive checking whereas revisors, editors, and proofreaders are held to a lower standard of diligence. If that is what is intended, "macro" and "micro" are not particularly apt words to distinguish between degrees of diligence for general readers.

**EDIT**: This answer was written before the original poster added content to the question. Please see comments below.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. I wouldn't be too interested in the *actual* translation efforts of whoever wrote the cited text!

Comment: Thank you, I Add a picture to my question. would you please check if we can come to a conclusion by that?

Comment: Yes. I have no problem with stipulated definitions in text that is not meant for the general reader. I must admit, however, that I prefer to indicate words used in a stipulated sense by starting them with a capital letter, e.g., Macro. That is a common convention in legal writing in the U.S., and I believe it to be useful (though admittedly rare) in other contexts.

Comment: This terminology is not anything to do with area of translation. It was invented by the author and may even be a translation from an Arabic text.

Comment: Good to know. But, in general, I do not mind idiosyncratic definitions in specialized texts if they are carefully disclosed before being used **AND** if the specialized field has no generally accepted  terms that make the distinction intended by the author. In this case, perhaps there is a better choice of words available, but I do not know because this field is not even close to any area of knowledge that I possess.